# Golang Standard Package Structure

Tags: go

I am faily new to Go and I am trying to create a structured application using guidance from Ben Johnson's webpage. Unfortunately, his example is not a complete working application.

His webpage is https://medium.com/@benbjohnson/standard-package-layout-7cdbc8391fc1

I have tried to use his methods and I keep getting "Undefined: db" error. It doesn't tell me what line is causing the error, just the file "MSSQL.go"

Could someone help with guidance to help me fix this error?

**Edited code with accepted solution.**

## StatementPrinter.go

```
    package statementprinter

    type Statement struct {
      CustomerId   string
      CustomerName string
    }

    type StatementService interface {
      Statement(id string) (*Statement, error)
    }
```

## main.go

```
            package main

            import (
              "fmt"
              "log"
              "github.com/ybenjolin/StatementPrinter"
              "github.com/ybenjolin/StatementPrinter/mssql"
              "database/sql"
              _ "github.com/alexbrainman/odbc"
            )

            const DB_INFO = "Driver={SQL Server};Server=cdc-edb2;Database=CostarReports;Trusted_Connection=yes;"

            var db *sql.DB

            func init() {
              var err error
              db, err = sql.Open("odbc", DB_INFO)
              if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error opening database connection.\n", err.Error())
              }
              err = db.Ping()
              if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error pinging database server.\n", err.Error())
              }
              fmt.Println("Database connection established.")
            }

            func main () {
              var err error
              defer db.Close()

              // Create services
              // Changes required here. Was ss := &statementprinter.Stat..
              ss := &mssql.StatementService{DB: db}

              // Use service
              var s *statementprinter.Statement
              s, err = ss.Statement("101583")
              if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Query failed:", err.Error())
              }
              fmt.Printf("Statement: %+v\n", s)
            }
```

## mssql.go

```
    package mssql  

    import (
      _ "github.com/alexbrainman/odbc"
      "database/sql"
      "github.com/ybenjolin/StatementPrinter"
    )

    // StatementService represents a MSSQL implementation of statemenetprinter.StatementService.
    type StatementService struct {
      DB *sql.DB
    }

    // Statement returns a statement for a given customer.
    func (s *StatementService) Statement(customer string) (*statementprinter.Statement, error) {
      var err error
      var t statementprinter.Statement
      // Changes required here. Was row := db.Query......
      row := s.DB.QueryRow(`Select Customer, CustomerName From AccountsReceivable.rptfARStatementHeader(?)`, customer)
      if row.Scan(&t.CustomerId, &t.CustomerName); err != nil {
        return nil, err
      }
      return &t, nil
```

Comment: Which line of which file is triggering the error?

Comment: It doesn't say what line is triggering the error. It just tells me that mssql.go is the file triggering it.

Comment: I see it: `row := db.QueryRow`. The error is right, `db` is not defined. What is it supposed to be referencing?

Comment: According to Ben Johnson's explanation, main.go is supposed to create a service and that is what mssql.go should be using. I'm just not sure how. The website is not clear on that. I'll put the link up in a bit.

Comment: `main.go` defines a `db` package variable, but it's in a different package from `mssql.go`, so it's not accessible from that file, for 3 reasons: it's not exported (it doesn't start with an uppercase letter); `mssql.go` doesn't reference it by its package; and it's in the `main` package, which cannot be imported from another package.

Comment: Isn't "ss := &statementprinter.StatementService{DB: db}" supposed to inject variable db into mssql.go?

Comment: No. You can't "inject" a variable into another package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like it's just a typo. It seems like the problematic line is in the method

```
 func (s *StatementService) Statement(customer string)
```

in mssql.go,

```
  row := db.QueryRow(`Select Customer, CustomerName From AccountsReceivable.rptfARStatementHeader(?)`, customer)
```

`QueryRow` is supposed to be a method of `db`, but `db` is not defined. However, in the struct

```
type StatementService struct {
  DB *sql.DB
}
```

there's a `*sql.DB` instance. The method you're using has a `*StatementService` parameter, `s`. So, my guess is the intention would be to access the `sql.DB` field in `s` like so

```
func (s *StatementService) Statement(customer string) (*statementprinter.Statement, error) {
  var err error
  var t statementprinter.Statement
   //CHANGED LINE:
  row := s.DB.QueryRow(`Select Customer, CustomerName From AccountsReceivable.rptfARStatementHeader(?)`, customer)
  if row.Scan(&t.CustomerId, &t.CustomerName); err != nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  return &t, nil
```

Then, the method is called in main.go, and is passed a `StatementService` instance that contains a database:

```
ss := &statementprinter.StatementService{DB: db}
```

I believe you need to change this line to

```
ss := &mssql.StatementService{DB: db}
```

becuase that's the actual interface implementation. The line you have now treats the StatementService interface like a struct which will not compile.
The global `db` in main.go lives for the lifetime of the application. It's just a pointer which is copied around for use.

Comment: The error message has changed. It looks like db is now defined but I now get main.go39:10: cannot assign *statementprinter.Statement to s (type statementprinter.Statement) in multiple assignment.

Comment: That's because `Statement(id string)` returns a `*statementprinter.Statement`, not a `statementprinter.Statement`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I still had a few typos to fix up once I implemented your recommendation. So it took a bit but I got it working. :)